# Serial communication with simulink

Tags: matlab, serial-port, simulink

I'm trying to send and receive data through a serial port using simulink (matlab 7.1) and d-space. The values I want to send and receive are doubles. Unfortunately for me the send and receive blocks use uint8 values. My question is how can I convert doubles into an array of uint8 values and vice versa? Are there simulink blocks for this or should I use embedded matlab functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the aptly named [Data Type Conversion](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/datatypeconversion.html) block, which does just that.

**EDIT following discussion in the comments**

Regarding scaling, here's a snapshot of something I did a long time ago. It's using CAN rather than serial, but the principle is the same. Here, it's slightly easier in that the signals are always positive, so I don't have to worry about scaling a negative number. 65535 is the max value for a `uint16`, and I would do the reverse scaling on the receiving end. When converting to `uint16` (or `uint8` as in your case, it automatically rounds the value, and you can specify that behaviour in the block mask).

[image]

Comment: How would this work in my case? Whenever I give a double as input and I set the output to uint(8), it only gives me a single uint(8) and not an array. I guess this is what I should expect, but how would I make sure it gives me an array of uint(8) representing the double?

Comment: Why should a "single" double be converted into an array of `uint8`, as opposed to a "single" `uint8`? What's the logic behind your desired conversion output?

Comment: I need to send the double over a serial port, which only accepts an input of type uint8. I thought I would break down the double into uint8's and then reassemble at the other side.

Comment: OK, then do some scaling on your `double`, break it down into several doubles if need be, or do whatever you need to do, and then convert each double into `uint8`. Do the reverse on the receiving end. It's standard packing/unpacking.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with scaling? And more important, how do I do it in simulink?

Comment: Take your double (scalar) data, normalize it by its maximum value (e.g. `realmax` or your own choice), add an offset so that it's always positive, multiply by the max `unit8` value (2e8 - 1), round and convert to `uint8`. On the other side, convert from `uint8` to double, divide by the max `uint8` value, remove the offset, multiply by the max `double` value. Use standard mathematical blocks for the scaling, then the data type conversion to go from `uint8` to `double` and vice-versa.

Comment: In my case that only gives 0 in the end. For instance if my input is 1.21, then after the scaling the uint8 is zero. Maybe I can convert it to a string and send it that way? Num2str doesnt seem to work in a simulink embedded code block...

Comment: Assume your input can vary between say -1000 and +1000. Divide it by 1001, it's now strictly between -1 and +1. Add 1, it's now between 0 and 2. Multiply by 2^7, your number is now between 0 and 2^8. Round it and convert it to `uint8`, do the reverse on the receiving end. The reason you get 0 is because of rounding errors. To avoid that, use a different scaling. Multiply (instead of dividing) your 1.21 by say 1,000 or an even larger number to retain the decimal places, and divide at the other end, still making sure you have a >0 nb.

Answer (score 0):

There are pack and unpack blocks in simulink, search for them in simulink library browser. You could need som additional product, not sure which.